# Kotlin Fuel HTTP Async VS. Blocking for user authentication

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm having issues with the way I authenticate my user in my Android application, here's how I do it right now:

When the Login button is pressed:

```
// Get user's email and password from the input
val user = User()
user.email = emailInput?.text.toString()
user.password = passwordInput?.text.toString()

 // Execute sign in request
 if (userService.signIn(user)) {
       Log.d("HTTP", "Success, switching to profile")
       // Login success, show profile page
       errorText?.text = ""
       val profileFragment = ProfileFragment()
       fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
             .add(R.id.fragment_container, profileFragment).addToBackStack("profile fragment").commit()
} else {
       // Login failed, show error message
       errorText?.text = "Login Error"
}
```

And here's my Fuel POST request:

```
fun signIn(user: User): Boolean {
    val url = "$ENDPOINT/signin"
    var success = false

    val json = JSONObject()
    json.put("email", user.email).put("password", user.password)

    val (request, response, result) = Fuel.post(url).body(json.toString()).responseJson()

    Log.i("Login", "Request to sign in user ${user.email}...")
    result.success { jsonRes: Json ->
        Log.i("Login", "Got response $jsonRes")
        val code: String = jsonRes.obj().getString("code")
        if (code == "200") {
            success = true
        }
    }
    result.failure {
        Log.d("HTTP", "FAILURE : $result")
    }

    return success
}
```

As you can see my request is blocking (thank to [Fuel](https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel)) since I want to return a Boolean to confirm that the log in was a success, but this brings up the 
`NetworkOnMainThreadException` exception.

Is there a better / more common way to handle sign-ins in an Asynchronous fashion? How can I tell my Fragment that the login was a success without waiting for the request on another thread?

Comment: You call `signIn` from UI-thread without coroutines. See https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel/blob/master/sample/src/main/kotlin/com/example/fuel/MainActivity.kt for an example. An other solution is using Fuel's callback `responseObject`. If I will succeed, I can write a solution. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50402433/how-to-use-fuel-with-a-kotlin-coroutine.

Comment: You can see it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53225660/2914140.