# How to use Fuel with a Kotlin coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Within an Android app, I'm trying to use [Fuel](https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel) to make an HTTP request within a Kotlin coroutine. My first try is to use the synchronous mode inside a wrapper like this:

```
launch(UI) {
    val token = getToken()
    println(token)
}

suspend fun getToken(): String? {
    var (request, response, result = TOKEN_URL.httpGet().responseString()
    return result.get()
}
```

But that is returning an `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. The Fuel documentation mentions .await() and .awaitString() extensions but I haven't figured it out.

What is the best way to make a Fuel http request within a Kotlin coroutine from the main UI thread in an Android application? Stuck on this - many thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling blocking code from a `suspend fun` doesn't automagically turn it into suspending code. The function you call must already be a `suspend fun` itself. But, as you already noted, Fuel has first-class support for Kotlin coroutines so you don't have to write it yourself.

I've studied Fuel's [test code](https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel/blob/master/fuel-coroutines/src/test/kotlin/com/github/kittinunf/fuel/coroutines/CoroutinesTest.kt):

```
Fuel.get("/uuid").awaitStringResponse().third
    .fold({ data ->
        assertTrue(data.isNotEmpty())
        assertTrue(data.contains("uuid"))
    }, { error ->
        fail("This test should pass but got an error: ${error.message}")
    })
```

This should be enough to get you going. For example, you might write a simple function as follows:

```
suspend fun getToken() = TOKEN_URL.httpGet().awaitStringResponse().third
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Newcomers, you can also see https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel/blob/master/sample/src/main/kotlin/com/example/fuel/MainActivity.kt for an example of `awaitStringResponse`.

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation "to start a coroutine, there must be at least one suspending function, and it is usually a suspending lambda"

Try this:

```
async {
    val token = getToken()
    println(token)
}
```

Comment: `launch(UI)` starts a coroutine. OP has it.